# Python Extracting dynamic amount of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm wondering how to best approach this problem. I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1
       3        4       5         6   
0    NaN      NaN     Sea       NaN
1  light   medium   light    medium
2     26     41.5      15        14
3     32       40      18        29 
4     41       29      19        42

df2
       3       4       5       6         7            8
0    NaN     NaN      NaN        Sea       NaN      NaN
1  light  medium    heavy      light    medium    heavy
2     26    41.5       21         15        14       29
3     32      40       19         18        29       31
4     41      29       18         19        42       35
```

And I am trying to isolate the 'Sea' column range as such:

```
df1
        5        6   
0     Sea      NaN
1   light   medium
2      15       14
3      18       29 
4      19       42

df2
      6         7         8
0      Sea      NaN         NaN
1    light   medium       heavy
2       15       14          29
3       18       29          31
4       19       42          35
```

My initial thought is to somehow drop the first column instances of 'light' and 'medium' or 'light' 'medium' 'heavy'. However I'm not quite sure how to achieve that. If anyone has a better idea/solution please feel free to let me know. I apologize for the lack of attempt but I really don't even know how to approach this problem

Comment: how can you have a column named both `'Sea'` and `'light'`. you should setup your data frame properly

Comment: @djk47463 those are not column names, but strings within the column. The column names are integers

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my answer to do it dynamically. May not be the fastest

```
for col in df1:
    if df1.loc[0,col] == 'Sea':
        break
    else:
        del df1[col]
```

Then you could do the same thing for the second Dataframe

Comment: thanks for the edits/answer! However I'm looking for a dynamic solution, I've been trying to find a way to return the column number of where 'Sea' is found and then trying to create a new dataframe where it's sea and onwards, if that makes sense